# Facebook Invite Friend Dialog app_non_users filter seems to have no effect

Tags: facebook, fbdialogs

I am building a Facebook Application that sits in a facebook page tab (and has a Canvas URL hook.) I am trying to implement the app_non_users filter.

When I introduce the filter, here is what I see:

- In both ['all'] and ['app_non_users'] everyone is shown (including those who have authorized the app)
- In ['app_users'] setting, no one is shown.

I am not running this on mobile, and I am passing the parameter in expected JSON form (proved by the fact that Facebook is doing different things for different values.)

I am also not using any other conflicting filters or even the "to" parameter. When I inspect the network tab, I see the following params being passed to FB:

```
message:Invite Message
title:Select from list of your friends
filters:['app_non_users']
api_key:xxxxxxx
app_id:xxxxxxxx
locale:en_US
sdk:joey
display:async
frictionless:false
redirect_uri:https://xyz.com
__d:1
__user:xxxxxxxx
__a:1
__dyn:798aD5z5CCU-wEbw
__req:9
```

Based on the above results, it seems to me that Facebook doesn't consider just app authorization to mean that a user is a app_user. So, exactly what makes a user app_user and how do I, as a app dev, make that change?

Answer (score 0):

From the question I think you are using the filter alone without any other filter for the Request dialog box. If that is correct then follow the bug [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/243409315785795?browse=search_518232fa27c327932127109) as it points to the same issue as you are having.

As an alternate, until the bug is fixed, I might suggest you to use more than one filter so that both of them work correctly. I tried the same with RELL [here](https://apps.facebook.com/fbrelll/saved/b634b57d091743e77522c378b46655f9).

Comment: Thanks. Let me test it out and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have subscribed to the bug. I have tried the hack mentioned in the link you gave, but that too isn't working. Using 'app_users' in conjunction with 'all', no one is shown, exactly as listed in the original report.

Comment: I have the same problem. Still no fix from facebok after 8 months. Have you guys found any workaround?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Dose anybody got this fix?

Answer (score 0):

I made workaround using 'exclude_ids' parameter and server side PHP.
Usng PHP I have populated exclude_ids with ids of current user's friends which already entered my app (I have those fb ids in my database), so Request dialog doesn't display those friends to user.

Comment: It will be messed when you have already invited 1000s of users